# Javascript closure: difference between accessing the model directly and using a variable

Tags: javascript

I've noticed that this code does not work as I expected.

Message RENDER_IMAGE is broadcasted multiple times with different image in payload, but self.model.get("image") in code below always returns last image. Why?

```
bus.subscribe("RENDER_IMAGE", (message, payload) => {
    const self = this;
    self.model.set(payload);

    self.render().then(function() {
            bus.broadcast("IMAGE_RENDER_COMPLETE", self.model.get("image"));
        });
});
```

Meanwhile this code works correct:

```
bus.subscribe("RENDER_IMAGE", (message, payload) => {
        const self = this;
        self.model.set(payload);
        const image = self.model.get("image"));

        self.render().then(function() {
                bus.broadcast("IMAGE_RENDER_COMPLETE", image;
            });
    });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Comment: So, can you not use the second approach then?

Comment: @Endless I need behaviour like in a second case. Am I right, that when I save image as a variable - it keeps this value until it will be used in promise? And why the model doesn't keep this value?

Comment: Yes, if you assign a variable it keeps it when you use it in the promise. Your problem is related to what @juhana mention but yours are a little bit different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first example you are retrieving the `image` field from the model *after* the render is completed.
In the meantime, one or more `RENDER_IMAGE` events could have been fired before the first render was complete. Every time such an event fires, you are updating the `image` field.

I.e. something like this happens

```
RENDER_IMAGE triggered
Set image field            (image = 0)
Start render (0)

RENDER_IMAGE triggered
Set image field            (image = 1)
Start render (1)

Render finished (0)
Get image field (1, because image = 1)

Render finished (1)
Get image field (1, because image = 1)
```

In the second example your are retrieving the `image` filed right after you set it. Since JavaScript is single threaded it is not possible that another `self.model.set(payload);` was called before `const image = self.model.get("image"));` is executed:

```
RENDER_IMAGE triggered
Set image field            (image = 0)
Get image field (0, because image = 0)
Start render (0)

RENDER_IMAGE triggered
Set image field            (image = 1)
Get image field (1, because image = 1)
Start render (1)

Render finished (0)

Render finished (1)
```

---

If you still wonder why there is a difference between accessing the model directly and using a variable instead: Every invocation of the event handler has it's **own** `image` variable, but they all access the same, **shared** model.

That's one of the characteristics of shared data, which is why shared data has to be handled carefully when dealing with asynchronous processes.

Comment: Thank you so much!